# Screen with multiple lists with background

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to build a scrollable screen which contains multiple lists.
To achieve that I am doing something like this:

```
LazyColumn{
     item{
     }
     items(list of items){
       ...
     }
     item{
     }
     items(list of items){
       ...
     }
     ...
}
```

My problems is that I would like to set a background to each list, but I can't set a modifier to the "items(list){}" object.
How can I build this screen? Should I approach the whole screen build in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each item in `LazyColumn` is an individual view, there is no parent view of the items within the same block: they are simply grouped by data.

You can apply the same background to every element in `items`, if you apply it before any paddings, it will look as you expect:

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
    item {
        Text("title 1")
    }
    items(10) {
        Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Blue)) {
            Text("hello $it")
        }
    }
    item {
        Text("title 2")
    }
    items(10) {
        Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Green)) {
            Text("hello $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!
The thing is that the background is not the same for all the elements, but I think that if I put a different background for the first element in the list and for the last one, I can get the wanted effect.

Comment: @user3356062 sure you can add use `itemsIndexed`  with a list instead of `items` to get the index and using `if` specify needed color